# Rails accessing javascript variable in template - Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try something : I have a gMap with markers.

In my `index` I initialise my google map, put markers etc. Everything is working.

On the left of my page I show the info of the 5 lasts markers on the maps (name, date etc.).

So for that I call a template named `_timeline`.

When I click one element I do an action -> Move the map. But For now, everytime I do this action, the map is reloaded (and markers are gone). I just want to see the map moving to center the marker.

But let's see my code, this is probably more simple :

my `index.html.erb`

```
<div class="row">

        <% @statuses_t.each do |status| %>
       <%= render partial: "statuses/timeline", locals: { status: status } %>
      <% end %>

 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({
  provider: {
    disableDefaultUI: true
    // pass in other Google Maps API options here
  },
  internal: {
    id: 'map'
  }
},
function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers((<%=raw @hash.to_json %>));
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
}
);


</script>
```

**`handler`** is the gMap

in `statuses/timeline`

```
... # some things

<script type="text/javascript">

$(<%="timeline_div#{status.id}"%>).on("click", function() {
    var centerpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(<%=status.latitude%>, <%=status.longitude%>);
      gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
      gMap.setZoom(13);    
      gMap.setCenter(centerpoint); // HERE
      gMap.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP); 
});

</script>
```

this create a new map when a click on the item, the probleme is : I don't want to reload a page, I just want to change re-center the map with `setCenter`.

So I want to use the **`handler`** variable from Index in my template.

How can I do that ?

Comment: return false from the on('click') handler? or stop the event propagation?

Comment: if `handler` is global: `handler.map.centerOn(<%=status.latitude%>, <%=status.longitude%>);`

Comment: yes, thanks you ! 
Using centerOn is better.
But centerOn put the map directly on the position, is that possible to have a movement ? as on the googlmap website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So

My variable vas already global ( template has the variable )

Thanks to comments, I had to do `handler.map.centerOn(<%=status.latitude%>, <%=status.longitude%>)`  and that's work